# How to remove alias from the eshell?

Tags: eshell

I recently created the alias in eshell:

```
alias hello 'echo "Hello World"'
```

So now whenever I type `hello`:

[image]

I am very used to creating temporary alias in the Terminal for more subtle use. And then putting my more permanent alias in the .bashrc file. So how do I remove the alias for hello? Do I have to set another alias for hello that does nothing? Is there an file that I have to edit to change this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `alias` command of `eshell` can also be used to remove aliases: just leave out the definition part.

```
$ alias hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no I don't have to open up any files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I went into my **home** folder and found the **.eshell** file. Inside I found a file named **alias** and opened it. That is where I found the place to edit and delete alias.